# Different thread limit between python 3.4 and 3.5?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have a python program that opens threads in a loop, each thread runs a method that sends an http packet. 
The program is supposed to emulate heavy traffic on a certain server we're working on.

The thread creation code looks something like this:

```
 while True:
        try:
            num_of_connections += 1
            thread_obj = HTTP_Tester.Threaded_Test(ip)
            thread_obj.start()
        except RuntimeError as e:
            print("Runtime Error!")
```

So again, the thread_obj is running a method which sends HTTP requests to the ip it is given, nothing fancy.

When running this code under python 3.5, I am able to open around 880 threads until the RuntimeError "can't open a new thread" is thrown.
When running this code under python 3.4 however, the number of threads keeps growing and growing - I got up to 2000+ threads until the machine it was running on became unresponsive.

I check the amount of threads that are open by looking at the num_of_connections counter and also using TCPView to verify in fact that the number of Sockets is actually growing. Under python 3.4 TCPView actually shows 2000+ sockets open for the program so I deduce that there are in fact 2000+ threads open

I googled around and saw that people suggested the threading.stack_size is the culprit - not here, I changed the size but the number of possible threads doesn't change either way

The question is, how come with 3.5 the limit is so low, whereas in 3.4 its (presumably) high? Also can I change the limit? I would prefer to use 3.5 but want to open as many threads as I can

Thank you!

Comment: This is crazy to create 880+ threads, use asynchronous I/O instead (`select` etc.). If you can I suggest you to use [gevent](http://www.gevent.org) or something similar.

Comment: I specifically want to create as many concurrent connections as possible to the server - hence why I chose threads. Will select allow me to do it? What are the advantages of it?

Comment: Yes you will be able to do concurrent connections, and much more than 2000... Threads are best used for CPU bound operations, here you're doing I/O only.